# Are ASM and TLA+ somehow related?

Tags: computation-models, temporal-logic, tlaplus

I learned about abstract state macines recently, and on first sight they seem somehow reminiscent to TLA formalism. For example both:

1. Are used to research possible state sequence and prove safety/liveliness properties abot them
2. Use notion of refinement
3. Have specification language on top of them

So I wonder does one have any formal connection between them? Is there at least some notion of temporal logic on top of ASM?

Comment: Have you checked the (now stale) [ASM web](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/gasm/), for instance the two papers linked on the [page about refinement](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/gasm/subjects/refinement.html)? They don't necessarily connect ASMs to TLA+ but to state-based modelling techniques in general. TLA+ is just one of those.

Comment: "Verification of ASM Refinements Using Generalized Forward Simulation" mentions relation to dynamic logic. It is an interesting source, but still, this is a less clear statement than I am looking for. I am interested if there are some theorems making specific relations/isomorphisms.

Comment: On p. 966 of that paper: "It is possible to view ASM refinement as an instance of data refinement, using the two ASMs as monolithic operations. In this case, our definitions of preservation of partial and total correctness coincide with the ones in [dRE98]." Chapter 14 of [dRE98] relates the semantic underpinnings of TLA+ refinement (Abadi & Lamport's refinement mappings + their auxiliary variable constructions) to the same basic principles as Schellhorn indicates. I'm not aware of anyone having made a direct connection between ASMs and TLA+ but doing so should be low-hanging fruit.